# Nested loop for C++

Tags: c++, loops, nested

I have to write a program that completes an algorithm and has at most 10 terms per line.  I'm having a problem 1) stopping the loop when it reaches 1 and 2) how to continue the loop for next incremented number.  Here's what I'm supposed to do and what I have.  I'm supposed to get a low term, high term, and increment.  The first calculation starts with the low term, and completes that, when completed the it's supposed to loop back to the low term + increment and do the calculations over again.  That is supposed to loop until it reaches the high number and finish that calculation. Without going through all of the code here's where I'm having trouble.

```
 void ulamCalc(double numOne, double numTwo,
               double increment)
 {
     int countOne, countTwo;
     countTwo = 1;

     do
     {
         for(count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
         {
             cout << setw(7) << numOne;
             if(numOne == 1)
             {
                 cout<< endl;
                 cout << OUTPUT_TERM << countTwo;
                 cout << endl << endl;
             }
                     countTwo++;
             if(static_cast<int>(numOne) % 2 == 0)
                 numOne = numOne / 2;
             else if(static_cast<int>(numOne) % 2 == 1)
                 numOne = (numOne * 3) + 1;         
         }
         cout << endl;
     } while(numOne >= 1);
```

This loop stops at 1 and outputs the number of terms, but then is followed by other lines that will repeat the last 3 calculations.  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a clue as to what you are trying to do here.    Please show sample inputs to the function, and expected output.

Comment: For example, the program asks the user to input a number between 1-1000 and then a 2nd number that's either equal to the first number or higher (<= 1000). The program will then ask the user to input an increment that is between 1 and the 2nd input number.  Then the program will calculate the sequence, even numbers will just be (x / 2 and odd numbers will ((x * 3) + 1).  The program will output 10 terms per line until the sequence reaches 1.  It will stop at 1 and then repeat the sequence with the starting term being low number + increment and repeat that sequence until it reaches the high term

Comment: input 100, 500, 200
Output:

100 50 25 76 38 19 58 29 88 44
 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10
 5  16  8  4  2  1

Comment: stackoverflow is great. So many experienced programmers doing ones homework for free. :-)

Comment: What is setw and what is OUTPUT_TERM? Paste your whole program here

Comment: @user2011734 of course, why else would we be on here? :))

Comment: And `return` after `cout << endl << endl;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple enough task but here are some ideas to help make writing this easier:

- give your variables better names. eg. `lowterm` `highterm` instead of `numOne` `numTwo`
- use `int` instead of `double`. Since the input and example output you've shown are whole numbers and integers, there's no real reason to use `double` here.
- break up the major steps into separate functions.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
void ulamCalc(int low, int high, int inc)
{
  for(int term = low; term < high; term += inc)
  {
    process_term(term);
  }
}

int main()
{
  ulamCalc(100, 500, 200);
}
```

outputs:

```
100 50 25 76 38 19 58 29 88 44 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 
300 150 75 226 113 340 170 85 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2
```

I'll leave `process_term` as *an exercise for the reader*.